# Can I use Django model function as a field in admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model function that returns a numerical value. I would like to be able to filter and sort by that value. When I tried adding it to `list_filter` Django complained that the model had no such field. Can I tell Django to treat it like a field? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use it as a class property, though I didn't try it?

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    @property
    def list_filter(self):
        """ Do your stuffs here """
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom filter and pass it in `list_filter`:

```
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter

class CustomFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    # Human-readable title which will be displayed in the
    # right admin sidebar just above the filter options.
    title = _('active status')

    # Parameter for the filter that will be used in the URL query.
    parameter_name = 'status'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return (
                ('active', _('Active')),
                ('not_active', _('Not Active')),
            )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        # do something here with queryset

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (CustomFilter, 'other_model_field')
```

Please see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) for more information about `ModelAdmin.list_filter`

Comment: The documentation link i have provided check the `DecadeBornListFilter` example, it will surely help you.